# In power bi how to change table colum header (visual table header) with custom template i am trying this but not working

Tags: powerbi

> I am trying this for column headers background but it's not working I check with key as background and backColor But it's not working

```
 "tableEx": {
                    "*": {
                        "columnHeaders": [
                            {
                                "fontColor": "#ffffff",
                                "wordWrap": false,
                                "fontSize": 12,
                                "urlIcon": true,
                                "backColor": {
                                    "solid": {
                                        "color": "#000000"
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        ],
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "wordWrap": false,
                                "fontSize": 10,
                                "urlIcon": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this theme generator:

https://powerbi.tips/tools/report-theme-generator-v3/